# How do I compile multi module Maven project where modules have different Java versions? Possibly using Jenv?

Tags: java, maven, multi-module, jenv, maven-toolchains-plugin

Suppose I have a multi-module Maven project, with two modules:

- `foo`; requires Java 1.8 to compile
- `bar`; requires Java 11 to compile

I'd like to be able to build these by running `mvn clean install` from the parent directory and have them compile using the appropriate Java versions.

Let's be clear: upgrading both to Java 11 is a non-starter.  Why:

- I want to upgrade application `bar` to Java 11 to get the latest features and improvements of the Java language.  `bar` is a standalone Spring Boot application and I am able to do that.
- Application `foo` is a JBoss deployment module plugin.  It's plugged in to a third-party app that at present is on Java 8.  I cannot drop a module compiled in Java 11 into an app running in Java 8.

I see that there is a way to do this using the [maven-toolchains-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html) as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414209/compile-maven-module-with-different-java-version).  That could work.  But I use `jenv` to manage versions, and it's possible to set the Java version per directory (using `jenv local`).  I'm wondering if there is a way to use Jenv to do this instead of the toolchains plugin.  It does just about everything I need; I just need to figure out how to get Maven to read the Java version from the jenv config file in the directory.

Comment: what's wrong with just compiling both projects with java 11 and moving on?

Comment: You may not migrate to jdk11 since it may well be incompatible. E.g. a class compiled with newer version may use instructions that are not available on newer jvm.

Comment: I cannot use Java 11 for project foo; it builds a drop-in to a third party app that runs only with Java 8

Comment: Though it's related, it's is not a duplicate of Compile Maven Module with Different Java Version.  I'm asking specifically about leveraging Jenv to solve this problem.

Comment: You can use java 11 to compile all projects, but you can set compatibility level for each sub module using the maven-compiler plugin -> just set the `source` and `target` to the required java version such as 7,8, etc and the java 11 compiler will produce java 7,8,etc compatible binaries.

Comment: @Svetlin the source/target compatibility level is useless when the project uses classes from the JRE that has been removed since Java 8 (e.g. java.xml.bind).

Comment: If he wishes to compile using older java, then he intends to run it on such, so I see no issue here. Also the removed APIs can be added as maven dependencies if necessary